# Rails 5 Survey client side answers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model MyQuiz that belongs to Quiz through Questions and also Belongs to User

Quizzes are created on models: Quiz and Question. So the model MyQuiz is the one that records the answers

I'm using SimpleForm so I came up with this form bellow for MyQuiz

```
  = simple_form_for(@my_quiz) do |f|
    = f.error_notification

    - @questions.each do |question|
      .form-group
        %p= question.title
        = f.input :answer, as: :radio_buttons
        = f.input :question_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => question.id }
        = f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }
    .form-group
      = f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"
```

my_quizzes_controller.rb

```
def new
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
  @questions = @quiz.questions.all
  @my_quiz = MyQuiz.new
end

def create
  @my_quiz = MyQuiz.new(my_quiz_params)
  if @my_quiz.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "Thank you taking the quiz!"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end

private

def my_quiz_params
  params.require(:my_quiz).permit(:question_id, :user_id, :answer)
end
```

The problem with this form is that it is not set properly to serialize the answers. So it acts as if all the answers are the same. Even the radio buttons are behaving the same way

I'm not quite sure on what I should do here. I also tried a hacky solution with simple_fields_for but it did not change the outcome.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE: With Suggestion and Another try**

So the suggestion was to MyQuiz form as a nested form

something like this:

```
    = simple_form_for @user do |g|
      = g.error_notification
      - g.simple_fields_for @my_quiz do |f|
        - @questions.each do |question|
          .form-group
            %p= question.title
            = f.input :answer, as: :radio_buttons
            = f.input :question_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => question.id }
            = f.input :user_id, as: :hidden, :input_html => { :value => current_user.id }
      .form-group
        = g.button :submit, class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"
```

1. I tried and still had the same problem with the radio button.
2. I'm thinking that it might be an unecessary call into UserModel create/update.

I've been  playing around with an option like this:

```
  = form_tag my_quizzes_path do
    - @questions.each do |question|
      %p= question.title
      = radio_button_tag "my_quizzes[#{question}][answer]", '0'
      = radio_button_tag "my_quizzes[#{question}][answer]", '1'
      = hidden_field_tag "my_quizzes[][question_id]"
      = hidden_field_tag "my_quizzes[][user_id]"

  = submit_tag "Submit"
```

Comment: Since you are using SimpleForm, please check [nested models](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/nested-models).

Comment: I don't think it's quite nested because I'm only saving the answers(MyQuiz). I'm not saving anything on Questions. Questions is more like a lookup table.

Comment: You can use nested form if you look at it this way: machine -> parts ; user -> answers. If you see it this way you are updating user info which happens to have some answers to create.